# Pythonize if/else

Tags: python

My mind is probably feeling Friday afternoon and I cannot see a way to pytonize the code below:

```
filepath = None
if 'HALLO' in os.environ:
    filepath = os.environ['HALLO']
elif os.path.isfile( os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'host.hallo') ):
    filepath = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'host.hallo')
elif os.path.isfile('/etc/app/host.hallo'):
    filepath = '/etc/app/host.hallo'
if filepath:
    print 'HALLO found in "%s"' % filepath
    ## do something
else:
    print 'HALLO not found!'
    ## do something else
```

Any idea on how to do it? Thanks!

ps: the code above is just an example, it can have a syntax error since I have written it directly here.

Comment: What do you mean by *pytonize*?  Write it in a more "*pythonic* way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
home_hallo = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'host.hallo')
filepath = ( ('HALLO' in os.environ and os.environ['HALLO']) or
             (os.path.isfile(home_hallo) and home_hallo) or
             (os.path.isfile('/etc/app/host.hallo') and '/etc/app/host.hallo') )
if filepath:
    print 'HALLO found in "%s"' % filepath
    ## do something
else:
    print 'HALLO not found!'
    ## do something else
```

See the documentation on [Boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) if it isn't clear why this works, here is the summary:

> The expression **x and y** first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression **x or y** first evaluates x; if *x* is true, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Comment: This is much harder to read, harder to understand and harder to maintain than the original code.  Shorter is not better.

Comment: Totally agree with Ferdinand Beyer. This is surely the less pythonic answer on this page.

Answer (score 10):

This should work pretty well:

```
paths = [
    os.environ.get('HALLO', None),
    os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'host.hallo'),
    '/etc/app/host.hallo',
]

for path in paths:
    if path and os.path.isfile(path):
        break
else:
    # Handle no path
    pass

# Use path here
```

Additionally, it allows you to add more paths to check easily.

Comment: Yeah, I like this solution better than the one accepted by OP.  But I'd add one little thing: Put a comma after '/etc/app/host.hallo'.  Python allows that and it'll make adding new entries a little easier as well as making reordering the list less error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the *first nonzero `filepath`*?  use `any()`.  You can also factor out the `os.path.isfile` using a list comprehension/generator expression.

```
filepath = any(filename 
               for filename 
               in (os.environ.get('HALLO'), 
                   os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'host.hallo'),
                   '/etc/app/host.hallo')
               if os.path.isfile(filename))

if filepath:
    print 'HALLO found in "%s"' % filepath
    ## do something
else:
    print 'HALLO not found!'
    ## do something else
```